Time and date stamp form control datacard when toggle control is set to true in PowerApps
Need help please. I have a form in powerapps where i capture the information then save it to Sharepoint.
In my form control, i have a toggle control where i want to auto populate the current date and time in another data card (textinput control) when the toggle is set to true (onCheck). I was able to capture the date and time but the problem is, when i view the old record the time stamp is always updating to the current instead of initial captured date and time values. when viewing the form item records, it should show the time stamp that was initially captured and not update to the current date and time. How can i handle both scenario?
Please see image below:
This is what's showing in the app:
App form
and this is what's in the data source (sharepoint);
Data Source Sharepoint
here is the code on the data card textinput control on the the Value property; If(DataCardValue12.Checked,Now(),Blank())
So far i tried; If(DataCardValue12.Checked,Now(),thisItem.Sales) - but this is showing blank even though there is a value on my data source.

From what I understand you want to display data stored in this field when you're viewing the form (form mode set to view or edit). If that true, below formula should fulfill your needs.
If(
    Toggle.Checked && Parent.Mode = FormMode.New,
    Text(Now()),
    ThisItem.Sales
)

If you want to set current date as text in this field WHEN the toggle is checked you should compare its current state to the value in the data source like below.
If(
    Toggle.Checked && Toggle.Checked <> ThisItem.ToggleValue,
    Text(Now()),
    ThisItem.Sales
)

